# call mp3player field (CCK Field) in a page

Tags: theming, 6, entities

I Use [MP3 Player](http://drupal.org/project/mp3player) module to play audio files. I'm looking for a PHP code to call MP3 Player from a specific node. (e.g. node 4) how can I do that ?

this code doesn't work:

```
<?php
$node = node_load(4);
print $node->field_audio[0];
?>
```

this is the result of `print_r($node)` in node 4.

```
stdClass Object (
[nid] => 4 
[type] => story 
[language] => en
[uid] => 1 
[status] => 1 
[created] => 1343931282 
[changed] => 1343931282 
[comment] => 2 
[promote] => 1 
[moderate] => 0 
[sticky] => 0 
[tnid] => 0 
[translate] => 0 
[vid] => 4 
[revision_uid] => 1 
[title] => 5455 
[body] => 
[teaser] => 
[log] => 
[revision_timestamp] => 1343931282 
[format] => 1 
[name] => admin 
[picture] => 
[data] => a:0:{} 

[field_audio] => Array ( 
[0] => Array (
[fid] => 7 
[uid] => 1 
[filename] => audio.mp3 
[filepath] => sites/default/files/audio.mp3 
[filemime] => audio/mpeg 
[filesize] => 3663455 [status] => 1 
[timestamp] => 1343931251 
[list] => 1 
[data] => 
)
)

[last_comment_timestamp] => 1343931282 
[last_comment_name] => 
[comment_count] => 0 
[taxonomy] => Array ( ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the readme.txt file of that module.

> Pop this code anywhere to insert an audio player:

```
if (module_exists('mp3player')) { 
  print theme('mp3player', 'Default', $audio_file_url, $audio_title, $audio_artist, $description); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before but It didn't work, I made some changes and now everything is ok: `<?php print theme('mp3player', 'Default', $node->field_audio[0]['filepath'], 'Static title'); ?>`